# Finding merged cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, formatting

I'm often trying to freeze columns in a Google Sheets and I get the error as below

The way I get around this is to manually hunt for the merged cells and unfreeze them, but this can be difficult on a large spreadsheet. Is there a way to identify the problem cells in a more automated way than manually hunting for them

[image: Sorry you can't freeze columns which contain only part of a merged cell Try to break apart merged cells or freeze more columns to include the complete merged cells]

Comment: you can use conditional formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if you have such an option you can use Conditional Formatting to check for merged cells where you can immediately spot merged cells where the color pattern is interrupted like:

  ```
  =MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0
  ```

  [image]

---

- in the same manner you can use this formula for rows:

  ```
  =MOD(ROW(),2)=0
  ```

  [image]